# Error: web3.toWei is not a function

Tags: web3js

Using Web3 version 1.0 and getting the following error:

> `web3.toWei` is not a function

Answer (score 22, accepted):

At Web3 version 1.0, utility functions like `toWei` and many others have been moved to the `web3.utils`.

To check all utility functions refer to:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html