# getting error web3.toWei is not a function when testing

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, erc-20

i have installed web3 latest version 1.0.0-beta.36. i am using helper libraries which i used from openzeppelin when i am running the test cases using truffle test it shows error as

> TypeError: web3.toWei is not a function

it's not just web3.toWei also i am also not able to use bignumber .i don't know why i am not able to use helpers from openzeppelin 
this is the file with the name of ether.js in helper folder

```
function ether (n) {
  return new web3.BigNumber(web3.toWei(n, 'ether'));
}

module.exports = {
  ether,
};
```

and for big number the code which shows error is

```
require('chai')
  .use(require('chai-bignumber')(BigNumber))
  .should();

const RefundableCrowdsale = artifacts.require('RefundableCrowdsaleImpl');
const SimpleToken = artifacts.require('SimpleToken');

contract('RefundableCrowdsale', function ([_, wallet, investor, purchaser, anyone]) {
  const rate = new BigNumber(1);
  const goal = ether(48);
  const lessThanGoal = ether(45);
  const tokenSupply = new BigNumber('1e22');
```

i have installed chai-bignumber and web3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: web3.toWei is not a function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48068/error-web3-towei-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @shane i have tried but it's not just web3.toWei also i am not able to use bignumber .i don't know why i am not able to use helpers from openzeppelin or my own helpers for for converting to wei from ether .but am not able to use them.

Comment: It would help if yoy posted the code. This sounds like a JavaScript issue rather than web3 or Ethereum.

Comment: @shane i have posted the code .check if there need to be any changes. i also wanna know it this the error in the new truffle beta version.

Comment: @shane thanks for everything i got the answer there is some error in the beta version of truffle 5.0.0-beta.0
so i changed the version to truffle 4.1.14. now all the test cases are running properly.

Comment: Probably because web3.toWei got moved to web3.utils.toWei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is some error in the beta version of truffle 5.0.0-beta.0
so i changed the version to truffle 4.1.14. now all the test cases are running properly.